# Mail from sendmail no longer delivered but SMTP does seem to work

Tags: linux, exchange, smtp, sendmail

On Sendmail (debian) In my mail.log I get the usual

`xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=120324, relay=foo.bar. [10.100.229.64], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent` [..] `[InternalId=43838731190661, Hostname=foo.bar] Queued mail for delivery)`

however my colleagues that admin the Exchange server which I've configured as a relay

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`foo.bar')
```

assure me that they are Not getting them on their server.

I also tried telnetting on `foo.bar` and send an email with the usual SMTP commands and that **did work**

How come sendmail is also reporting 2.0.0 was sent back from the server and yet email is not sent?

The only thing they say they've done is changed the internal DNS to have a redirect for anything `.bar` to their domain controllers, I dont know what that means but `foo.bar` resolves correctly on my server and as stated earlier SMTP commands over a telnet session on it worked.

Comment: The message "Queued mail for delivery" does mean that relay server accepted mail for delivery. Are they sure that they have checked maillog on the host 10.100.229.64?

Comment: Yes.. the last emails in the logs were before the DNS change (which we think is the only change that happened). Also, `postfix` seems to work too It must be the way `sendmail` relies on using hostnames perhaps

Comment: You can check it, try to replace fqdn with ip address - 'define('SMART_HOST','10.100.229.64')'

Comment: I tried that, just fails, sendmail tries to resolve the IP as if it's a hostname.

Comment: You must use square brackets - [10.100.229.64]

Comment: In the log the domains did resolve to the right IP too. However now that I tested postfix on a dev server I had to move over to postfix on these as a solution and no longer have sendmail configured like that to test.. Then again Im sure it'd have failed its sendmail after all.